# Syntax error with assembly

Tags: assembly

My teacher gave me this assembly code to program a MC9S08SE8 microchip but I can't compile it due to a syntax error. I keep searching in Internet but I can't found what the error is related to, I don't know what instruction should be there to run it.

```
mainLoop:
          INCLUDE 'MC9S08SE8.INC'        
          ORG   Z_RAMStart
CH          DC.B  0        
          ORG   ROMStart
RST        LDA   #02
          STA   SOPT1
          MOV   #$FF,PTBDD
          MOV   #$FE,PTADD
          MOV   #0,SCIBDH    
          MOV   #31,SCIBDL    
          MOV   #$00,SCIC1    
          MOV   #$0C,SCIC2
          MOV   #$80,PTBD
          CLR  CH

      BRCLR 0,PTAD,*
      BRA   ASK
PREG     BRCLR 7,PTBD,APAG
          BRA   ENC

ENC       CLRH
         CLRX
OT        BRCLR 7,SCIS1,*
     LDA ON,X
         STA SCID
         AIX #+1
         CPX  #9
         BNE   OT
     BRA   ASK

APAG    CLRH
        CLRX
OTR     BRCLR 7,SCIS1,*
        LDA OFF,X
        STA SCID
        AIX #+1
        CPX  #7
        BNE   OTR
        BRA   ASK

ASK        7,SCIS1,* ;Sintaxis error
        LDA   SCID
        CMP   #$30
        BNE   S
        BCLR  7,PTBD    
S       CMP   #$31
    BNE   SS
        BSET  7,PTBD
SS        CMP   #$32
    BNE   ASK
        BRA   PREG      

OFF     DC.B  $41,$70,$61,$67,$61,$64,$6F
ON      DC.B  $45,$6E,$63,$65,$6E,$64,$69,$64,$6F
```

Comment: If you search "syntax error" that should help you actually find the answer - when i searched syntaxis  - google automatically translated it back to syntax which makes sense for what your doing

Comment: You need to give more details like the command you used try to assemble the code and the exact error message.

Comment: `ASK        7,SCIS1,*` is not an instruction, probably an error during copy&paste, `ASK     BRCLR 7,SCIS1,*` should assemble